# Callback on xhr request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, xmlhttprequest

When I use Google chrome dev console to run my code I have some problems.
My current page is vk.com. I use this code

```
var request_url = 'https://vk.com/dev/openapi';//similar domain
var requestData = function(request_url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', request_url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
                var content = xhr.responseText;
                console.log(callback(content))
                callback(content);
            }
        }
    xhr.send();
};

var dataEl = requestData(request_url, function(content) {
        var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
        el.innerHTML = content;
        return el;
});
```

it does not work because dataEl is undefined but console.log show me ... ei what I want.

if code like this is used:

```
var requestData = ...(similar)
var contentNew = requestData(request_url, function(content){return   content});
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = contentNew;
```

el is not empty or undefined object. It's what I want.

How should I use XHR without manual input?

Comment: You can't do that. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: You seem to be attempting `var foo = (function () {/* something using foo which hasn't been set yet*/}());`

Comment: @SLaks it's very strange. Why then exist callbacks in xhr objects? I don't understand how to use this anywhere.

Comment: @saga111a: Because it's asynchronous.  Read my blog post and its prequel.

Comment: @SLaks I suspect OP actually just wanted to `el.innerHTML = content;` instead of `= dataEl`

Comment: @PaulS.: That entire variable makes no sense.

Comment: @SLaks `content` is the parameter of the callback, `content = xhr.responseText; callback(content)` is happening in the _readystatechange_ handler. You're right that the use of `dataEl` is wrong, though

Comment: @SLaks: I read you post by link. Two years ago I used similar methods with jq but now don't remember how I implemented it. May be jq more convenient of course... Thanks in any case

Comment: @SLaks: >That entire variable makes no sense.<
fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to `return` from a *callback*, either chain more callbacks or make your code event driven.

Other than that and some old coding styles, your only mistake seemed to be trying to set `el.innerHTML = dataEl;` when you seemed to want `el.innerHTML = content;`

Here is a demo of using an *XMLHttpRequest*

```
function xGET(url, callback, error_callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', callback);
    if (error_callback)
        xhr.addEventListener('error', error_callback);
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr; // why not?
};

var my_url = '/'; // for demo

xGET(my_url, function () {
    var el;
    // creating a <html> doesn't make much sense
    // this example will use a <div> instead
    el = document.createElement('div');
    // do something with your XHR's data
    el.textContent = this.responseText;
    // do something with `el`
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}, function () {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.textContent = 'Something went wrong :(';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
});
```

[**DEMO** on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8xr3m1o/)

Comment: for me it's similar with that I wrote above, but it works! Thanks.